# .htaccess www - redirect (R301) with dynamic domainname

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

I want to redirect 3rd or 4th level domain to add "www.":

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ /home/ [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^(?!www[\.]) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=/$1 [QSA]
```

My problem is that it could be a different number of levels...
www . froschkoenig84 . bplaced . net
www . froschkoenig84 . de

So when it's not starting with "www." then add, else not...

> RewriteRule ^(?!www[\.]) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

But it doesn't work, ... it's adding each time... so it's ending like...
[image: add "www." each time]

How can I check if it starts with "www." or not?
If possible, then without a separate condition. :)

I created similar rewrite rules for .NET (web.config), too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
   <rules>
    <rule name="RedirectToHome" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^$" />
     <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
      <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{ToLower:{C:1}://{HTTP_HOST}/home/}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RedirectToWWW" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false"  />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?://)(?!www[\.])" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{C:1}www[\.]{R:1}}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RewriteToParams" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
      <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{ToLower:index.php?p=/{R:1}}" appendQueryString="true" />
    </rule>
   </rules>
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain name is not part of the test uri in RewriteRule.

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

worink solution:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
 #RedirectToHome
  RewriteRule ^$ /home/ [R=301,L]

 #RedirectToWWW
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]

 #RewriteToParams
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=/$1 [QSA]
```